# Check if Cell is empty to break while loop

Tags: c#, excel-interop

Hello I work on a method to extract data from Cells. This works but every time I reach an empty cell I get a `NullBinderException`.

My question is how can I prevent this?

Here is the part that makes problems:

```
    while ((range.Cells[startpoint, cell] as Excel.Range).Value2.ToString() != null)
    {
        for (int i = 1; i <= numberOfColumns; i++)
        {
            string sValue = (range.Cells[startpoint, cell] as Excel.Range).Value2.ToString();
            stringList.Add(sValue);
            cell++;
        }
        startpoint++;
        cell = 1;
    }
```

Stuff that I tried:

`range.Offset` = Cant use becouse this is not an aviable Member.
`IsNullOrEmpty` = Makes no difference

So there is something I don't get. Any help or advise would be great and thanks for your time.

Comment: `Value2` will be `null` if the cell is empty.  You can't call `ToString` on it safely.  Just check `...Value2 != null` instead.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: you could [try-catch (Referencia de C#)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/0yd65esw.aspx) your `nullBinderException`.

Comment: @CharlesMager this isnt a duplicate. My question is what i can use in an excel specific case.

Comment: @AndreasA it's still a duplicate.  Following the answer to that question would have lead you to discover what is `null` and shown you what to do to fix it.  This isn't really specific to Excel.

Comment: @CharlesMager Oh ok now i know what you mean. Thanks for pointing it out to me. And sorry....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Cell Range and/or Value2 may be null. Check these within your Where clause.

```
while ((range.Cells[startpoint, cell] as Excel.Range) != null && (range.Cells[startpoint, cell] as Excel.Range).Value2 != null)
{
    for (int i = 1; i <= numberOfColumns; i++)
    {
        string sValue = (range.Cells[startpoint, cell] as Excel.Range).Value2.ToString();
        stringList.Add(sValue);
        cell++;
    }
    startpoint++;
    cell = 1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make your while loop as:-

```
while (! IsNull(range.Cells[startpoint, cell] as Excel.Range).Value2))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try catch you exception like:

```
try
{
  while ((range.Cells[startpoint, cell] as Excel.Range).Value2.ToString() != null)
  {
    for (int i = 1; i <= numberOfColumns; i++)
    {
        string sValue = (range.Cells[startpoint, cell] as Excel.Range).Value2.ToString();
        stringList.Add(sValue);
        cell++;
    }
    startpoint++;
    cell = 1;
  }
}
catch(nullBinderException e)
{
   //you find an empty cell
   //... break? jump over and continue?
   //... your logic...
}
```